# Example of a ring satisfying this variant definition of "symmetric" on nilpotent elements

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

I want an example to show that if $a,b$ are nilpotent elements of a ring $R$ with 1 and if $c$ is any element of $R$, then $abc=0\Rightarrow acb=0$ but $cab=0$ does not imply $acb=0$.

This is unlike symmetric ring, where we know that if $a,b,c\in R$ and $abc=0$ implies that $acb=0$.

Please help me to find a ring where to search for an example or help me to show that if $abc=0 \Rightarrow acb=0$, then $cab=0 \Rightarrow acb=0$ for above mentioned $a,b,c$.

Comment: Just to clarify the question: you want to know whether there exists a ring with unit such that whenever $a, b$ are nilpotent and $c$ is any element with $a b c = 0$, then also $a c b = 0$, but also such that there is some $c$ such that $c a b = 0$ and $a c b \neq 0$? Also, I think by "symmetric", you mean commutative.

Comment: This is crossposted from MSE. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/508386/example-of-a-ring-satisfying-this-variant-definition-of-symmetric-on-nilpotent

Comment: @ Todd Trimble: No, symmetric and commutative are not same. Every commutative ring is symmetric but converse is not the truth.

Comment: Okay, thanks for saying so. I had to look up "symmetric ring": a ring R is called *symmetric* if $abc=0 \Leftrightarrow acb=0$ for all $a,b,c \in R$. According to this paper by Greg Marks http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022404902000701 the notion was introduced by Lambek.

Comment: I want to clarify the second condition: $\forall a,b \ \exists c \ cab=0\ {\rm does\ not\ imply\ }\ acb=0$ or $\exists a,b, c\ cab=0\  {\rm does\ not\ imply\ }\ acb=0$?

Comment: Boris Novikov: $\exists$ nilpotent elements $a,b$ in $R$ and $\exists c\in R$ such that $cab=0$ but $acb\neq 0$, but for all nilpotent elements $a,b\in R$ and for all $c\in R$, $abc=0 \Rightarrow acb=0$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand correctly, there are two conditions on the ring $R$:

(1) if $a$ and $b$ are nilpotent elements of $R$, and if $c$ is arbitrary, then $abc=0$ implies $acb=0$;

(2) if $a$ and $b$ are nilpotent elements of $R$, and if $c$ is arbitrary, then $cab=0$ implies $acb=0$.

There exists a ring for which condition (1) is satisfied, while condition (2) fails.  Indeed, let $k$ be a field, and let $R$ be the path algebra of the quiver
$$ 1 \stackrel{x}{\leftarrow} 2 \circlearrowleft^y $$
over $k$, modulo the relation $y^2=0$. Let $e_1$ and $e_2$ be the paths of length $0$ at vertices $1$ and $2$, respectively.  I compose arrows from left to right: $xy$ is a non-zero path, while $yx$ is not.

Then any nilpotent element is a linear combination of $x$, $y$ and $xy$.  Let $(ax + by+ cxy)$ and $(dx+ey+fxy)$ be two such elements, and let $(ge_1 + he_2 + ix + jy + lxy)$ be an arbitrary element. We have
$$(ax + by+ cxy)(dx+ey+fxy)(ge_1 + he_2 + ix + jy + lxy) = (aeh)xy \\
 (ax + by+ cxy)(ge_1 + he_2 + ix + jy + lxy)(dx+ey+fxy) = (aeh)xy.$$
Thus condition (1) is satisfied.  However, we have that $e_2xy = 0$, while $xe_2y = xy \neq 0$.  Thus condition (2) is not satisfied.

Comment: Well, this looks right. OP has offered a 300 point bounty over at the MSE version of the same question, if you want to claim your prize over there.

Comment: @ Pierre-Guy Plamondon: Thanks for the answer. Had you provided your affiliation, it would have been esier for me to acknowledge you in all of my future works relating to this.

Comment: @ToddTrimble Thanks for your suggestion.  I wasn't sure if it was considered OK to answer the same question on both sides.  I'll copy my answer at MSE, providing a link to this one.

Comment: But I see that you've already mentioned this answer in an edit of the MSE question.  Maybe reposting the answer is not necessary then.

Comment: @Pierre-GuyPlamondon I was the one who made that edit. I felt this was the right thing to do.

Comment: @Anupam Pierre-Guy Plamondon's affiliation is quite readily available from his user page, although citations in the literature, and to MO answers in particular, basically never use 'affiliation' -- the name and source is sufficient.

Comment: @ToddTrimble Thank you for the edit on the MSE side.